# Compile a Maven dependency with another JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, restlet

I have a project using the JDK 1.5 (due to project legacy) and I want to use Restlet. For the moment I got the current build part in my pom.xml:

```
<build>

    <plugins>
        [...]
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.5</source>
               <target>1.5</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>       
    </plugins>

  </build>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <restlet-version>2.2.1</restlet-version>
        <spring-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I am running `mvn install` through Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] src/main/java/com/****/SomeFile.java:[3,-1] cannot access org.restlet.Component
bad class file: ****\.m2\repository\org\restlet\jse\org.restlet\2.2.1\org.restlet-2.2.1.jar(org/restlet/Component.class)
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
```

I understand the error is because I am trying to compile a project with Java 5 but using a Java 6 library. How can I use or compile my dependencies also with the JDK 1.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use an older version. If you check the [Official Restlet Framework Blog](http://blog.restlet.com/category/rest/restlet/restlet-releases/), it says the following in the 2.2 version news:

> *We no longer support Java 5 which has been the case since Restlet Framework version 1.0. If you still need to support Java 5 due to other requirements, we encourage you to keep using Restlet Framework 2.1.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't use them without recompilation. For that to work you'd need the source code and in many cases some build script to get the build done correctly.

The java version is part of the .class files and because you told Maven to compile for Java 5 the compiler will refuse to just use .class files having a version higher than 49.0 (which is the class file version of Java 5).

So you need .class files having version 49.0 and thus you need to recompile the library and probably its dependencies too. In that process you might even have to take into account that the code might make use of newer language features or JDK libraries so that might be a huge task. In many cases it might be better to try and raise the restrictions to use Java 6 or find another library.